# What is the difference between 形成, 构成, 组成, 养成?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, vocabulary, difference

According to the dictionary, 成 has meanings of to become or to form, what is the subtle difference between 形成, 构成, 组成 and 养成?

Comment: I suggest you to look up the compounds, rather than the individual characters. No +1 from me today for this reason. Would be a much more valuable question if you had done some research and are stuck on more specific nuances.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up a dictionary first, as they are quite different, except for 组成 and 构成. Compared with 组成, 构成 sometimes emphasize the interaction between constituents, but they are very similar in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

形成: to form to some situation or status by developing a progress of action

构成, 组成: consist of

构成 and 组成 can be used interchangeably in most of case.

养成 is a bit different from the other 3 words. It means to cultivate (a habit).